# What benefits howler.js brings for a basic audio player in comparison to `audio` element?

Tags: audio, howler.js

Preconditions:

- Developing an audio player for a web application.
- All target browsers fully support `audio` tag.
- No need in sprites, multiple simultaneous sounds etc, just one audio track to be played back at a moment.
- Audio file has to be streamed from the server, not downloaded at once. Therefore not Web Audio API.

**Why would I want to utilize [howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js) or similar library instead of relying on the built-in `audio` tag in this scenario?**

The only [howler.js feature](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#features) that is intriguing is  “Handles edge cases and bugs across environments”.

Comment: I think the “Handles edge cases and bugs across environments" is exactly the reason.